# Hyphenation "kinetic"

Tags: hyphenation

What is the correct hyphenation of "kinetic" (if it matters in British English). I found two possibilities:

> **ki-net-ic** (/kə-ˈne-tik/) in the [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinetic) (which might be US English) and **kin-et-ic** (/kI'netIk/ or /kaI'netIk/) in the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary 8th edition (British version?).

Is there a difference in hyphenation rules between British and US English?

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of [Hyphenation of “balaclava”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/41545/19644), but the accepted answer to that question is unsatisfying. Also, the wikipedia article on [syllabification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification) simply says, "*there are differences between British and US syllabification and even between dictionaries of the same English variety.*" It would be great to get a more thorough answer from the community.

Comment: I've been mumbling 'kinetic' to myself for 30 seconds; I'm not sure I see a difference.

Comment: There is no official hyphenation in English. All punctuation is a matter of individual opinions, occasionally codified, but all contradictory. Phonologically, there is often no letter-perfect ending of on syllable and beginning of the next. In _kinetic_ [kʰɨ'nɛɾɨk]there are two consonants, [n] and [ɾ], that separate syllables; the question is whether the first syllable is [kʰɨn] or [kʰɨ], the second syllable is [nɛ], [nɛɾ], [ɛ], or [ɛɾ], or  the third syllable is [ɾɨk] or [ɨk]. The problem is that the [n] nasalizes the first syllable, and the [ɾ] occurs between stressed and unstressed.

Comment: After reading what @JohnLawler said, I wonder if a better question is the more general one: Are there any particular letter formations that make it hard to figure out where syllables should be separated?  E.g., would _fanatic_ give us the same problem as _kinetic_? (And, in the case where it's ambiguous, does that mean one could hyphenate it in either place, if the word needed to be hyphenated in a paragraph of text?)

Comment: Those are two separate questions. Hyphenation is strictly an artifact of the technology of printing and reading; how you hyphenate is between you and your editors. Syllables, however, have fuzzy edges, especially when they could swing either way, like _bedridden_ and _bedraggled_. My nominee for the hardest English word to syllabify would be _squirrel_; it can vary from one to 5 syllables (though 5 is rare except in Japanese English). But syllables are always being omitted in this stress-timed language. Oh, and it's not **letters**; it's **sounds**. Letters are technology.

Comment: Hyphenation rule: never hyphenate after a short vowel (unless not doing so breaks another hyphenation rule). If it's pronounced /kɪnɛtɪk/, you hyphenate after the 'n'; if it's pronounced /kənɛtɪk/, you hyphenate after the 'i'. What do the two dictionaries say about the pronunciation?

Comment: @PeterShor I added the pronunciation as given in the dictionaries. This supports your comment.

Comment: I'm really curious about the commenting here - this is the 4th unanswered questions I've seen with a very good answer in the comments (Peter Shor's), rather than being an actual answer that can be accepted. This is much different than the other SE sites I frequent. Is there a particular reason?

Comment: @JohnLawler: "I have two animals – a dog, and a squirrel." No idea how it's syllabified, or how many syllables (maybe 2?), but it's one of my favorite quotes of all time (as heard between 0:50 and 0:55 of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nn0UkdDArM)). As for my previous post, I was only basing that off guidance I've seen in the past, like: "Use a hyphen to divide words at the end of a line if necessary, and make the break only between syllables" (found [here](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/), Rule #5). But, as you point out, it's not always so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of guidelines for hyphenation in English. one of them is:

> Don't hyphenate after a short vowel.

Following this guideline you get: If it's pronounced /kɪnɛtɪk/, hyphenate after the 'n'; if it's pronounced /kənɛtɪk/, hyphenate after the 'i'. I suspect this is the reason for the difference between the two dictionaries.

One side comment: the actual hyphenations given by *Merriam-Webster* don't follow a single set of rules: they involve judgment calls where two of these rules conflict (e.g. *rational*) and some cases where historical hyphenations no longer make sense (*fair-y* and *prai-rie* seem to be hyphenated the way they are because they didn't rhyme 100 years ago).

And as a final side comment: I am sure that both pronunciations are used by Americans.

Comment: So you’re saying that you only can hyphenate after `ɔː`, `ɑː`, `eː`, `iː`,  `oː`, and `uː` then, not the other vowels?

Comment: Also after ə. The idea is that you can only hyphenate after vowels which can end words in English.